# Adding shebang causes No such file or directory error

Tags: python-3.x, ros

I have a python file that I need to run. I have made sure to make it executable. I have added a shebang to environment python3 and I have been having no such file or directory error when trying to run this code.

I have tried to convert the line endings to unix format using dos2unix and the error still occurs. The works fine when i run it directly without shebang using python3 file_name.py command.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import roslib
roslib.load_manifest('joint_states_listener')
roslib.load_manifest('spider_control')
import pylab as plt
```

This python file a custom plugin that has to run with ros. I have made sure to source the catkin environment. Do you think that shebang expression error is caused because I have sourced the terminal to another catkin directory where my ros packages are located ?

I have launched my robot in a terminal using 
     `roslaunch spider_gazebo spider_world.launch` 
this command says ros to launch the spider_world launch file from spider_gazebo package. This has started all my controllers. Later i opened terminal and I exported my ros environment paths and sourced that terminal to catkin workspace and then used this command 
    `rosrun spider_control control.py` 
where control.py is my python node and spider_control is the package. the error is
    `/usr/bin/env: python3.6.7:` No such file or directory

Comment: Whats the command you run, and what is the full error message?

Comment: I have launched my robot in a terminal using 
   `roslaunch spider_gazebo spider_world.launch`
this command says ros to launch the spider_world launch file from spider_gazebo package. This has started all my controllers. Later i opened terminal and I exported my ros environment paths and sourced that terminal to catkin workspace and then used this command 

`rosrun spider_control control.py`

where control.py is my python node and spider_control is the package.

the error is 
 `/usr/bin/env: ‘python3.6.7’: No such file or directory`

Comment: Sounds like the environment doesn't have a /usr/bin/env to be run. Maybe you should change to `#!/usr/bin/python3` (or where-ever python3 resides.)... *I didn't see your edited comment. Add that information to your question though. It might help somebody figure it out.*

Comment: What happens if you use `which python3`, it sounds like you have a broken sym-link which is why /usr/bin/env python3 looks for python3.6.7, but cannot find it.

Comment: it says '/usr/bin/python3'. although I have found the error. Its because  I was not updating my workspace where I am running the simulation. I am just fixing the error and pushing it to my GIT repository but not fetching it from GIT to my workspace. Thanks for your time.